# Converting 1D array to 2D array in C

Tags: c

I recently wrote the following code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int **x;
  int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
  x = (int**)arr;
}
```

How can I print the contents of arr using x ? Also explain how can 1D array be converted to a 2D array ?

Comment: That code is broken.

Comment: Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: You can convert an 1D array to a 2D array, BUT it dangerous because you change how to access of a amount of bytes. If you don't do correctly, it will result of undefined behavior. Also, doing that with an odd number of data it's simply impossible.

Answer (score 1):

1) What you are trying to do is incorrect. You have to use a `int *`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int *x;
  int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
  x = arr;

  //do what do you have to do

}
```

2) For the array conversion I guess it makes no sense.

Comment: I know what I did does not makes any sense. But it is not incorrect as the code compiles without warnings. My doubt is how can a 1D pointer converted to 2D one.

Comment: If you mean how this conversion can be done: the operation `int **x = (int**)arr;` is syntactically correct. You will obtain a `int` pointer to `int` pointers or(more simple to understand) a `int[][]`